# Retaining overall height with expanding divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 div elements that expands when hovered.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="box_1" class="box active"></div>
  <div id="box_2" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box_3" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Currrently, the divs becomes smaller than the container whenever the user **quickly** hovers around all 3 divs. How can I set it up that it will always have a total height equivalent to the container.

I've created a JSFiddle to recreate the problem I have: http://jsfiddle.net/uLzva50r/2/

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uLzva50r/4/) what you looking for ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!